# Convert XML String to SOAPBody

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, soap-client

What is the proper way to convert the XML string to SOAPBody. Below is my Implementation

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlResponse.getBytes());
SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);
SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody();
```

I'm getting [SOAP-ENV:Body: null]. xmlResponse is an input parameter for the method.

Comment: Are you only looking to get the body elements? Or the whole XML?

Comment: No I'm not looking to get the body elements, Just need to convert the XML to SOAPBody

Answer (score 0):

First, for you to set the body xml on SOAPBody, you need to provide the complete structure of xml(envelope node and etc..), later you need to remove only header node and his node childs.

Second, you're setting the body xml in wrong layer. Bellow follows an example:

```
//This needs be your body xml that you want to set on SOAPBody
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlResponse.getBytes());

//convert inputStream to Source     
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(is);
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);

//create new SOAPMessage instance       
MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance(javax.xml.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL);
SOAPMessage message = mf.createMessage();
SOAPPart part = message.getSOAPPart();

//Set the xml in SOAPPart 
part.setContent(domSource);
message.saveChanges();


//access the body
SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody();

//for you to access the values inside body, you need to access the node childs following the structures.
//example
body.getFirstChild();
```

I think this will solve your problem.